# Do overloading operators have address?

Tags: c++

Do overloading operators have address,that i can put them in vector, for example like this `vector<int> v = { &operator(+),&operator(-),&operator(*),&operator(/) };`,and then if i write this `int a= 1(*v[0])2` it equals to `a=1+2=3`?

Comment: Actually, yeah, just not for builtins. The overloaded operators are basically just functions. Can you clarify if you meant the builtin operators, or the overloaded ones?

Comment: overloaded ones

Comment: 1) "_for example like this `vector<int> v = { &operator(+),&operator(-),&operator(*),&operator(/) };`_" This wouldn't compile, since the actual type of `operator+`, depends on its definition, but it would never be equal to `int`. In addition to the fact, that there's no such thing as `operator(+)` (it's `operator+`). 2) "_if i write this `int a= 1(*v[0])2` it equals to `a=1+2=3`?_" This wouldn't compile either. Usage would need to be as a regular function pointer.

Comment: Perhaps the functional operators, e.g. plus<T>, minus<T> etc. would be more useful for your purpose?

Comment: You can wrap overloaded (or non-overloaded) operators in a lambda, `auto v = vector<function<Foo(Foo const&, Foo const&)>>{ [](Foo const& rhs, Foo const& lhs) { return rhs + lhs; } };`

Comment: OP: "overloaded ones". vote to reopen, as the dupe is about builtins only

Answer (score 3):

You can use pointers to function and store lambdas there. Something in this way:

```
auto plus = [](auto a, auto b) { return a + b; }
auto minus = [](auto a, auto b) { return a - b; }
...
vector<decltype(plus)> v = {plus, minus, ...}
```

Comment: Please do not use backticks `\`` for codeblocks, but instead use four spaces in front of each code line.

Comment: what would be the type of `vector<>` ? I am not familiar at all with that new fancy deduction stuff, but you need to declare the type somewhere, no?

Comment: I updated my answer